# Using ancestorInheritedElementForWidgetOfExactType in flutter

Tags: dart, flutter, inherited-widget

I have a chat object in a `InheritedWidget` above to root widget of my app. I want to access this object within `initState` to set the initial state of a child widget. I've the following code:

```
void initState() {
  super.initState();
  final inheritedWidget = context.ancestorInheritedElementForWidgetOfExactType(MyInheritedWidget).widget;

  inheritedWidget.chat.someFunction();
}
```

I'm getting an error saying:

    `"The getter 'chat' isn't defined for the class 'InheritedWidget'`

Am I using the method wrong, how do you use it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to cast `widget` first:

```
final inheritedWidget = context.ancestorInheritedElementForWidgetOfExactType(MyInheritedWidget).widget as MyInheritedWidget;
```